# Is it possible to call Sharepoint REST API with Javascript from outside of Sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, php, rest, sharepoint

I have a list in Sharepoint and I would like to create an external webpage that displays the content of this list. I would like to perform a REST call to Sharepoint using Javascript or PHP.

I have read about the REST api but still don't know if it is possible to use it outside of Sharepoint. Anyone with experience?

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross-domain security restrictions, you can't call SharePoint's REST API directly from outside of SharePoint.

An alternative is to use an iframe to display a SharePoint page, put your JavaScript that needs to communicate directly with the REST API on the SharePoint page, and use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between your external page and the embedded page in the iframe.

A few caveats:

- Both the embedded page in the iframe and the hosting page should be using the same protocol, either HTTP or HTTPS.
- The SharePoint page (or SharePoint environment) must be set to allow its content to be hosted in a frame.

If you have SharePoint Designer or some other tool for editing ASPX pages, you can add a control to the page that allows the page to be embedded in an iframe.

```
<% Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"/>
```

JavaScript running on the page that is embedded within the iframe can invoke `parent.postMessage(data,url)` to send data to the hosting page. (The second parameter must match the hosting page's origin for security.)

To listen for and respond to the receipt of data on the host page, add an event listener to trigger on the "message" event.

```
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceived);
}else{
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", onMessageReceived);
}
```

You can send additional details to the page embedded in the iframe using query string parameters (for initial configuration) or additional postMessage invocations (for two way communication).

Sending a message to the embedded window in the iframe from the hosting page is similar to sending messages the other direction: the difference is that you'll need to get a reference to the iframe's `contentWindow` property and call `postMessage` on it.